# Arduino Hash Table/Dictionary

Tags: hashmap, arduino, hashtable

I am trying to get a Hash Table or Dictionary to work on the Arduino Mega 2560. My goal is to have something like

```
dictionary[ENGLISH]["ACCOUNT"] = "Account";
dictionary[ENGLISH]["DATE_AND_TIME"] = "Date and Time";
dictionary[ENGLISH]["IDLE"] = "Idle";
dictionary[ENGLISH]["Language"] = "Languge"
dictionary[ENGLISH]["MAIN_MENU"] = "Main Menu";
dictionary[ENGLISH]["PRESCRIPTION"] = "Prescription";
dictionary[ENGLISH]["SETTINGS"] = "Settings";
dictionary[ENGLISH]["SOUND"] = "Sound";
```

where ENGLISH is essentially a constant 0, and I will have SPANISH and FRENCH as well (1 and 2 respectively). That is, an array of 3 dictionary elements.

On a first Google search, I found a [link](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/) to a library that models the C++ STL, but it is not working on Arduino 1.0.3 for me at all. I was wondering if anybody had an alternative for using maps/hash tables in arduino for me, **or** a fix to get the library mentioned working.

For some context of my situation, I am modeling a menu system via a touchscreen on the Arduino, it has to accept 3 languages (for the buttons). The chosen language is found in a location in EEPROM and I'll keep it in the variable 'lang', when I need to print something to the screen, I'll do something like:

```
    screen.print(dictionary[lang]["SOUND"], CENTER, 23);
```

and depending on the 'lang' the user has chosen, it will print accordingly, ideally.

Comment: How about `std::map<int, std::map<std::string, std::string> >`?

Comment: At this point there is no standard library for the Arduino as far as I know, the one I mentioned above is not working for me (I understand what you are suggesting: instead of making an array of dictionaries, make one dictionary with the 'lang' being the first element in the dictionary, but I don't have a way to use maps right now.) (I clarified my question!)

Comment: How many entries will you have for each language?

Comment: Perhaps this: http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/HashMap

Comment: @user529758 Arduino doesn't have a stdlib implementation. Nothing in the `std` namespace is present.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think a hash table may be unnecessary here, and there are good reasons to avoid it on this platform anyway.

### Why a hash table may be unnecessary

Usually in such situations there is no need for a **string** key, since the key is visible only inside your code, and the key is not interacted with from outside your program. Thus, the usual solution is to have a (pseudo) integer key, in the form of `#define` which is handled by the preprocessor and not your program:

```
#define kWORDIDX_LANGUAGE   1
#define kWORDIDX_SOUND      2
#define kWORDIDX_MAINMENU   3
#define kWORDIDX_SPAGHETTI  4
...
dictionary[ENGLISH][kWORDIDX_SOUND] = "Sound";
...
```

You can then access your dictionary entries like this `Sreen.print(dictionary[lang][kWORDIDX_SOUND], CENTER, 23);` or something similar.

The advantages of this approach are:

- You are saving memory space: no string keys are used
- You are saving processing time: while hash table access is technically O(1), there are still constant factors involved to compute the hash. Array access is faster.
- You code is less prone to errors: if you misspell your key using string accesses (which are a form of magic numbers anyway) you'll get a hash table miss.  If you misspell one of the `#define`d keys, you get a compile error, which is what you want

### Why you don't want a hash table on an Arduino

Arduino is a memory-constrained platform: it has very limited memory. The problem with using a real hash map is as follows:

- Strings take up more memory space that `int`s (usually). Using `#define` keys, which are converted by the compiler to integer literals, you are using 1, 2, or 4 bytes per key (depending on your compiler settings), whereas each string key requires `strlen(s) + 1` memory space to store. This space is actually used twice: once in Flash (that is where variables are initialized from) and once in SRAM.
- The hash map data structure itself takes up more memory: there is the overhead of either empty entries in the hash map (in [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing) scheme) or of the linked list (in the [separate chaining scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining)). Since your data is read-only you don't need that overhead, since the hash table will not be added to.
- One trick people use to save on memory in Arduinos is storing read-only data (such as strings) in [program memory](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM) only (and not SRAM) using the `PROGMEM` keyword. If you build your dictionary using a hash map, this route will not be available to you. On the other hand, given a `#define`-type indexing scheme as above, it will be very easy to store all your language strings as `PROGMEM` strings.

Comment: Very well written! Can you go into more detail about how I can use PROGMEM for the method you outlined above? I've used it before for storing sprites when drawing onto the screen, but nothing like this. Thanks!

Comment: Probably best to take a look at the "Arrays of Strings" section [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PROGMEM): that has a complete example of `PROGMEM` table of `PROGMEM` strings.  It's just that instead of `strcpy_P(buffer, (char*)pgm_read_word(&(string_table[i])));` (or similar) you'd use `strcpy_P(buffer, (char*)pgm_read_word(&(string_table[kMY_DEFINED_INDEX])));` (or similar). If that doesn't help maybe post another question here: it seems like it is a bit of a different topic. What do you think?

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to hear it.

Comment: And why I do want a hash table: If data is passed to an Arduino and you need to parse and store it on the Arduino in a flexible way, some kind of string-string-dictionary (= a hash map) would be perfect for that job. While I generally do agree very well with your statements please have in mind that you will not be able to avoid all kinds of use cases.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use a data structure to define a dictionary:

```
typedef struct { 
  uint8_t lang;
  char* sound;
  char* value;
} langDictionary;
```

Then you can define an array of the structure with the values to be used:

```
const langDictionary myDictionaryArr[] {
    {0, "ENGLISH", "Settings"},
    {1, "SPANISH", "Ajustes"},
    {2, "FRENCH", "Paramètres"}
};
```

And finally you can use the array to search the properties:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  for(uint8_t i = 0; i < sizeof(myDictionaryArr)/sizeof(langDictionary); ++i) {
      Serial.println(myDictionaryArr[i].value); //Prints the values: "Settings", "Ajustes" and "Paramètres"
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a good trick, when you want to simulate dictionary, where the key is the Array's Index.

Answer (score 4):

while i perfectly agree with the previous answers, the [arduino playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/) has as "[HashMap Library for Arduino](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/HashMap)".

Comment: using HashMap Library gives error missing`WProgram.h` missing.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz, this is unrelated to using a library in general - please include the mentioned file in your code.

Comment: if I use `HashMap.h` in the code: I get the compilation error:

`~/Arduino/libraries/HashMap/HashMap.h:33:22: fatal error: WProgram.h: No such file or directory`
 `#include <WProgram.h>`

                     `^`
`compilation terminated.`

Comment: alright, try either removing the `include` statement or changing the filename to `Arduino.h`.

Comment: @clankill3r can you please be more specific?

Comment: The playground has a note:
  Hint: This is NOT a real hashmap, it's a key-value-map. Searching in this 
  "HashMap" is done via simple iteration over all entries, not via hashed-key.

A "hashmap" that performs look ups in O(N), full scanning the data, is NOT a hashmap but a sugar coated array

Comment: I found that you cannot overload this Arduino hashmap to use a custom struct, it only stores ints :(